# Moving on from Social Sound Design

Tags: discussion

Now that we've lost this avenue to converse in, lets move on somewhere else. At the moment I believe The Sound Collectors Club has the most members from the old SSD. I haven't joined but I do think that would be a nice new place to call home when I do.

Also don't forget we still have the SSD Facebook page. We can carry on there without having to deal with the broader topics this SE site seems to garner. Just search for the Social Sound Design page in FB.

See you guys there!

Comment: I wonder who moved this post? What's wrong with this being on the main page telling people where to go? Tsk tsk...

Comment: This post is precisely what the meta site is for.  It didn't belong on the main site... it's not a question about sound, it's a question about the site.  I didn't move it, but I would have if I'd seen it first.

Comment: @takuya - I moved it here because it is not a question about sound design (as you so much like to point out that you don't like having non-sound design related questions on the main site.)  I was nice enough to leave it up despite the fact that it is not even attempting to be constructive at helping the community here.  As you can see from the activity it's seen, the community is more frustrated with this fatalist kind of attitude about the community here on the site.  If you don't like it here, then please feel free to go, but don't just keep complaining without working with the community.